# Checking for NULL dates in custom code function

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to implement a function for my SSRS report which will return a color value depending on the values of three dates:

```vb
Function SetBoxColor(dateOne As Date, dateTwo As Date, dateThree As Date) As String
' Determine colors for text box
  If (dateOne Is Nothing) Then
    SetBoxColor = "Blue"
  Else
    If (dateThree Is Nothing) Then
      If dateOne >= Date.Now Then
        If DateDiff("d",dateOne,Date.Now) < 90
          SetBoxColor = "Yellow"
        Else
          SetBoxColor = "White"
        End If
      Else
        SetBoxColor = "Orange"
      End If
    Else
      If dateThree <= dateOne Or (Month(dateThree) = Month(dateOne) And Year(dateThree) = Year(dateOne)) Then
        SetBoxColor = "Green"
      Else
        SetBoxColor = "Red"
      End If
    End If
  End If
  Return SetBoxColor
End Function
```

The parameters passed to this function are nullable date (SQL Server date type) from my dataset and I call the function from a TextBox's BackgroundColor property as:

```vb
=Code.SetBoxColor(Fields!dateOne.Value, Fields!dateTwo.Value, Fields!dateThree.Value)
```

Running the function as is returns the error:

> 'Is' requires operands that have reference types, but this operand has the value type 'Date'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried `dateOne = Nothing` ?

Comment: That worked. I am used to SQL Server not being able to evaluate NULLs with = and was just assuming 'is' was what i needed.