# Trying to get Reporting Services to understand my code

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I'm trying to encapsulate some expressions that I need quite frequently in my reports into report functions, so that I could write the code once and use it everywhere in my report. *But I'm really a Pascal / C# programmer and struggle with the VB(A) syntax.....*

But even this tiny date formatting function somehow doesn't work...

```
Public Function DateFmt (ByVal dt As DateTime) As String
    Return IIF(IsNothing(dt), "", FormatDateTime(dt, 2))
End Function
```

Basically, if a `DateTime` field is `NULL` in the database, I want to show an empty string (empty cell), otherwise use the "short date" formatting option.

On a cell, I'm trying to add this as the cell expression, but when I start typing the expression like this:

```
=Code.
```

the intellisense kicks in, but my function isn't shown in that list..... hmm.... what am I missing?

> **Update:** I noticed that while intellisense doesn't work, I can still put the expression `=Code.DateFmt(.....)` into the cell - but alas, it doesn't work.
>
> While adding the expression directly nicely suppresses `NULL` dates in display, using this shared function causes `NULL` dates to show up as `01.01.0001` again in my report. ***WHY?***

Also: I need to have a function that returns a value depending on a list of choices - a `SWITCH` statement basically. Is this code here correct?

```
Public Function GetGrp(ByVal grp As String)
    Select Case grp
      Case "Region"
          Return fields!RegionId.Value
      Case "Somedate"
          Return YEAR(Fields!Somedate.Value)
    End Select
End Function
```

This function actually causes compilation to fail, with this error message:

> *Error in line 7 of user-defined code: [BC30469] Reference to a non-public member requires an object instance*

<strike>?!?!?!?!? What exactly is SSRS trying to tell me here?</strike>

**Update #2:**
OK, figured this one out - the `Fields` collection isn't available in custom code (no clear why not - anyway....).

So I needed to change this function to :

```
Public Function GetGrp(ByVal grp As String, ByVal fields As Fields)
```

and now that part works

Comment: about the null dates showing up as `01.01.0001`: it could be that `IsNothing()` is not the right check. Try using `IsNull()` instead.

Comment: @w0lf: but **why** does it work when I type in this expression directly - but not when I encapsulate this into a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IsNothing` *vbscript* expression doesn't seem to work very well in custom *VB* code. If you change the custom code to this it may work:

```
Public Function DateFmt (ByVal dt As DateTime) As String
    Return IIF(dt = Nothing, "", FormatDateTime(dt, 2))
End Function
```

Solution distilled from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184745/checking-for-null-dates-in-ssrs-custom-code-function).

Comment: @marc_s: Caution, IIF is not a short-circuit operation, it evaluates both sides before it returns the result. Probably FormatDateTime already handles NULL values, but i wouldn't bet on it without trying. Additionally, if you export this report, it doesn't show the date correctly in Excel. Use d in the Format property of your table cell. That works fine in all supported formats and uses the appropriate short-date locale.

Comment: @marc_s: Additionally, FormatDateTime uses the currentculture of the thread/ui, so if somebody has his browser set to another language, it will format the date in that language. Probably you will only want to have the results in English, so you should set the appropriate culture/locale in the report, and use DateTime.ToString("format") instead of FormatDateTime.

Comment: @marc_s: PS: This is because Nothing is not equivalent to null, Nothing is equivalent to default(T).

Comment: @Quandary: `FormatDateTime` does **not** handle NULL dates correctly - not at all (it returns `01.01.0001` in Central European format - Jan 1, 0001). That was the reason behind trying to come up with a function to do this...

Answer (score 2):

The VBA way of returning a value from a function is to assign the value to that function name; I don't think there's a `return` keyword.

That's possibly also the reason why the functions don't show up in the intellisense list.

Try to define the functions like this:

```vb
Public Function DateFmt (ByVal dt As DateTime) As String
    DateFmt = IIF(IsNothing(dt), "", FormatDateTime(dt, 2))
End Function

Public Function GetGrp(ByVal grp As String)
    Select Case grp
      Case "Region"
          GetGrp = fields!RegionId.Value
      Case "Somedate"
          GetGrp = YEAR(Fields!Somedate.Value)
    End Select
End Function
```

#### Update:

Also, the VBA code in SSRS is more like a collection of static functions, meaning that they cannot access report state (such as parameters/fields).

I would try passing the two `fields!*` values as `byval` parameters to the `GetGrp` function.

---

Note: *I don't have SSRS or Office to test this code, so please let me know if something fails.*

Comment: Thanks - I tried this: there's no difference - I still get an error about the `fields` in the `GetGrp` function